# charting in the terminal commander cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, charts, command-line-interface

I intend to take up a project that builds out a CLI using commander that makes requests to an API.

I am wondering how I would go about adding basic charts in the terminal that are similar to [image: this] and a graph functionality in the terminal (similar to the GitHub contributions graph).

I am unable to find good npm packages for this (a python alternative for this is [termgraph](https://pypi.org/project/termgraph/)), any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure of any ready made solutions, but using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk should be pretty easy to do

Answer (score 7):

I don't know any package that display chart for the terminal, however, this can be done all by you using [`chalk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk).

This package allow you to display color within the terminal, it will be your job to format the `console.log` so it get printed with the right colors and width.

Otherwise, a quick search on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=terminal%20chart), using `terminal`+`chart` keyword gave me the following interesting results:

- [ervy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ervy)
- [cli-pie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-pie)
- [cli-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-chart)
- [terminal-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminal-bar)
- [ascii-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ascii-chart)
- [asciichart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asciichart)